# Levenshtein Distance for a List

Tags: python, loops, text, cluster-analysis, levenshtein-distance

I want to divide my word list into some number of clusters using Levenshtein Distance.

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
Target_Column = data["words"]
Target = Target_Column.tolist()
clusters = defaultdict(list)
threshold =5
numb = range(len(Target))

for i in numb:
    for j in range(i+1, len(numb)):
        if distance(Target[i],Target[j]) <= threshold:
            clusters[i].append(Target[j])
            clusters[j].append(Target[i])
```

But as I am running loop over list some clusters are repeated. Please help me to sort this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you only have strings, why not use a set?

```
Target = set(Target_Column.tolist())
```

---

You can also use a default value of a set for your mapping:

```
clusters = defaultdict(set)
```

But this requires changing `list.append` to `set.add` in your loop.

---

There is, however, a more pythonic alternative to your code.

I would probably generate a mapping from words to the set of their connections on the fly.

Here is an example assuming `words` is a `set` of all words:

```
clusters = {w1: set(w2 for w2 in words if distance(w1, w2) <= threshold) for w1 in words}
```

Live example:

```
>>> distance = lambda x, y: abs(len(x) - len(y))
>>> words = set("abc def abcd abcdefghijk abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv".split())
>>> threshold = 3
>>> for cluster, values in clusters.items():
...     print cluster, ": ", ", ".join(values)
...
abcd :  abcd, abc, def
abc :  abcd, abc, def
abcdefghijk :  abcdefghijk
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv :  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
def :  abcd, abc, def
```

Increasing threshold we get one big "cluster" for all words:

```
>>> threshold = 100
>>> clusters = {w1: set(w2 for w2 in words if distance(w1, w2) <= threshold) for w1 in words}
>>> for cluster, values in clusters.items():
...     print cluster, ": ", ", ".join(values)
...
abcd :  abcd, abc, abcdefghijk, abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv, def
abc :  abcd, abc, abcdefghijk, abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv, def
abcdefghijk :  abcd, abc, abcdefghijk, abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv, def
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv :  abcd, abc, abcdefghijk, abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv, def
def :  abcd, abc, abcdefghijk, abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv, def
```

Comment: Suppose I have a list with 6 words                                                        Target = ('Ajay','Tree','Man','Tiger','Ajad','Trend')                                  Loop will start from 1st word and create cluster using for loop cluster 1 is 'Ajay ','Ajac'  but as loop reaches to 4th index it will again create another cluster having words 'Ajac','Ajay'. One option is to delete that word after adding to 1 cluster but it will give me error Index out of range.

Comment: @AjayJadhav I've added an example.

Comment: **I am taking distance from Levenshtein** <br/>  from Levenshtein import distance

Comment: How is that relevant? Simply replace the distance function with whatever distance function you like over your elements.

Comment: @ Reut Sharabani Let me clear, I have 1 list containing 1000 words. I just want to create clusters to divide that list into small list   Answer should be like  cluster_1 = (tree,trend,trim)  Cluster_2 = (App,Apple,Pinapple)

Comment: Problem is one word is repeated in 2 or more clusters